# List of valid locations for matplotlib legend location

Tags: python, matplotlib

I take a legend location on the command line of a Python script, some string suitable to be passed to the `loc` parameter of the [legend()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) command.

I'd like to validate that the location is valid before I proceed with the script (potentially taking a long time and then failing near the end due to a bogus location).

How can I programatically get the list of valid "string"<sup>1</sup> locations for the current matplotlib version?

---

<sup>1</sup> By "string" locations I mean the locations written in English, like `upper left`. You may assume I handle arbitrary locations like `(0.5, 0.75)` separately.

Comment: There are infinitely many valid locations, since `loc` can be a tuple of two numbers. If you only want to check predetermined locations, you could do `dic = matplotlib.legend.Legend.codes
print(loc in (*dic.keys(), *dic.values()))`. Worth noting that I [did plan to](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12679) change this, so possibly we will deprecate the `.codes` attribute at some point in the future.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - thanks, I forgot about the tuple locations, I wanted to know about the "english" locations: I can validate that is one of those _or_ something that can be converted to a tuple.

Comment: What do you consider a "valid" location?

Comment: @DizietAsahi What they consider valid is what you get via `matplotlib.legend.Legend.codes.keys()` as stated above.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see. I thought the OP wanted to find a position where the legend was covering the lest amount of data or something of the sort. Nevermind

Comment: @DizietAsahi - yes, that's 'best' in parlance above. Sometimes I want the user to explicitly be able to specify an location like `upper left` and sometimes they need to work around bugs in pandas/matplotlib.